# aria-live is interrupted by other labels, how to stop this behavior?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I currently have this div with aria-live=assertive:

```
<div id="accesibility__ready" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></div>
```

Currently in my js file I have a method for setting everything in page with a tabindex (first headlines) then the `<p>`'s. Once this method is finished I want to notify user through my aria live that he can now navigate with tab:

```
  var ariaAlert = document.getElementById('accesibility__ready');
  ariaAlert.setAttribute('aria-label','Content updated tab navigation ready');
```

I have noticed that sometimes the aria-live is read but then it gets interrupted by all the other labels (that are not aria-live), that somehow the screenreader decides to read.

I'm using Chrome and ChromeVox extension.

So How do I stop aria-live from being interrupted by some other labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't sound like `aria-live` is being used correctly.  `aria-live` is intended to be used on an element if the contents/children of that element will change.  This includes adding/removing/changing text on the element itself (such as `textContent`) or adding/removing DOM elements nested under the element.  See the [W3 spec on `aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) for full details.

`aira-live` is **not** used to indicate when an attribute of the element has changed.  That is, using `aria-live` on a `<div>` and then changing that div's `aria-label` will **not** be announced.

`aria-atomic` controls how much is read when a change happens.  Should only the specific thing that changed be read (`aria-atomic="false"` - the default) or should the entire element be read (`aria-atomic="true"`).

For example,

```html
<div aria-live="polite">
  this message will self destruct in 
  <span id="counter">X</span> 
  seconds
</div>
```

Without `aria-atomic` specified (and thus the default value of `false` is used), if you update `counter` to '5', then **only** the value of counter will be announced, "5".  However, if you use `aria-atomic="true"` on the `<div>`

```html
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
  this message will self destruct in 
  <span id="counter">X</span> 
  seconds
</div>
```

then when you change `counter` to '5', you'll hear "this message will self destruct in 5 seconds".

As a few side notes.  You should always try to use `aria-live="polite"` unless you have a message that is super important that needs to interrupt whatever else is being read.  Rarely are there cases where `aria-live="assertive"` have to be used.  Using `assertive` might also clear other messages that are pending to be read.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live
>
> "User agents or assistive technologies **MAY** choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs"

And finally, the whole premise to your question sounds like you have an option that makes all headings and paragraphs tabbable (tabindex="0").  I don't know the purpose of that option, and you might have a legitimate reason for doing so, but if the purpose is to "help" screen reader users navigate to all the elements on your page, you'd be doing the screen reader user a **disservice**.  Screen reader users already have great navigation mechanisms built into the screen reader itself.  For example, on a PC, a JAWS or NVDA user can navigate to all the headings by using the 'H' quicknav key.  Or they can display a dialog that shows all the headings.  They can navigate to various other elements with similar shortcut keys ('B' to move to the next button, 'T' to move to the next table, 'R' or 'D' to move to the next landmark, 'L' to move to the next list, etc).  VoiceOver on iOS has the rotor which allows a similar type navigation to headings, buttons, tables, etc.  So as long as your page uses semantically correct html (such as `<h2>` for a heading instead of just a style to make the font larger and bold), then you should be ok without a feature to make everything focusable.

Comment: You went an extra mile with the last part thanks! :) So even though ChromeVox can not focus on other p elements without tabindex=0 other screenreaders actually do. Good to know

Comment: ChromeVox has the same feature.  Go into your chromevox settings and look for the chromevox modifier key.  It's the first keyboard shortcut in the list.  You can set it to ctrl, or shift, or alt, or a combination of these.  Let's say it's "ctrl".  If you then look further down the list to the "ChromeVox Navigation" section, you'll see "ChromeVox+Down arrow" is "navigate forward".  So if I press "ctrl+downarrow", it will move to the next DOM element and I can get to paragraph elements.  Look further down to "Jump Commands" and "ctrl+N,H" will take me to a heading, "ctrl+N,L" to a list, etc.

Comment: About your "this message will self-destruct in X seconds": in my testing what this would actually do is speak "your message will... your message will... your message will..." because any update will take over the previous. Is this expected? Is there a way to tell the SR to wait until the previous status message has finished reading? (tested with VoiceOver on Firefox/Chrome)

Comment: @RobinMétral, that's partially controlled by the screen reader itself. If I have a piece of text that updates quickly and updates faster than the screen reader can keep up, then some screen readers will queue up all the changes and keep announcing them until they're all read. Others might read as much as they can then if the queue gets too big, then drop some of them so it can catch up. It also depends if you're using `polite` or `assertive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @slugolicious! I'll do some more testing with different settings and SCs then. FWIW I was using `polite` and was surprised because I thought only `assertive` would interrupt