# Are the boxicons not compatible with the accessibility?

Tags: html, icons, accessibility

I am using icons from boxicons but the documentation says that to use it in html, I have to declare it like this :

```
<i class='bx bx-user'></i>
```

Isn't it an accessibility problem to use the i tag? And if it is, what should I change to make my page more accessible?

Comment: Ironically I just answered a very similar question on font awesome where all the same principles should apply, doe it answer your question on how to make icons accessible? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62340579/2702894. Ignore the first paragraph as that was specific to the question, the fiddle and advice is all relevant though.

Comment: Thank you. So, I add aria-hidden="true" attribute to the icon and I had a hidden span (with your visually-hidden class) that describes the icon ?

Comment: yeah that is exactly it. Just bear in mind that you should describe the state the icon represents if it is a check, cross etc. (e.g. selected, cancel etc.) If that answers your question I will mark this question for closing as duplicate if that is ok?

Comment: Ok, thank you ! You can close this question !