# How to make an HTML link displayed as an icon accessible?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have some links that are displayed only as icons (don't have any text):

```html
<a href="..." class="icon-link"></a>
```

```css
.icon-link {
  background-image: url(...);
}
```

How do I make this link accessible for people not accessing the website visually (using screen readers)?

I see few approaches possible, but cannot find any resources on which one is actually right, or best supported:

- Adding `aria-label` attribute on `<a>`
- Adding `title` attribute on `<a>`
- Adding text inside `<a>` and then hiding it visually with CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

Use visually hidden text.

### Longer answer

Adding a `title` offers very little in the way of accessibility. [Here is an interesting article on the subject](https://silktide.com/blog/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/), it links out to further information.

So with that in mind that leaves option 1 and 3 as viable options, however the best compatibility is using visually hidden text.

You see [support for `aria-label` is surprisingly low (scroll down the page to the `aria-label` section)](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/), whereas visually hidden text using the example below will cover browsers all the way back to IE6!

I answered about the most robust way to do visually hidden text (with explanations of why I do each item) in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894). I have copied the same below just for your reference.

For your use case just add a span within the link with the visually-hidden class.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<p>visible text <span class="visually-hidden">hidden text</span></p>
```

### Added Bonus of visually hidden text

As @QuentinC pointed out in the comments there is another great reason to use visually hidden text over the other methods.

If a user uses a browser that does not support CSS (there are still a few text only browsers that people use) then the text will be displayed.

Comment: I'm having one question about your answer. Isn't there a good way to visually hide text without introducing extra `<span>`? Something like `text-indent: 9999px;` or `color: transparent;`.

Comment: No because it actually gets set on the parent rather than the content. So if you tried to apply this to the link itself it would hide the whole link. Sadly this is the limitation of this method. If can be automated fairly easily though if you have a lot of these to correct.

Comment: Also if you do `color: transparent` that will likely hide the icon itself (as it is a font) but will also mean that the text still takes up the same space on the page (it is still rendered even if you can't see it) and same with `text-indent: 9999px;` - text-indent may also break the reading order so that one is defo one to avoid.

Comment: No, I apply icon as a background image in CSS, not as a font in the markup.

Comment: Anyway, now I understand why other approaches aren't good. Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: With the visually hidden solution comes a bonus. IF the user is using a browser without CSS support, it stays usable:  the text will visible.
This isn't guaranteed at all with the two other solutions.

Comment: I cannot believe nobody has ever made me realise that before @QuentinC, will add that as a bonus in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Always reconsider using visually hidden text. Not because it is bad, but because it leads to false belief that the solution is accessible for everyone when it's only accessible to a small subset of the population.

Using hidden text won't help people not using screenreaders to know the action performed by the link when meaning of the image might be difficult. Screenreader users are a small part of the population targetted by accessibility rules.

Regarding the `title` attribute, it won't hurt anyone to improve accessibility if you inform standard mouse users of the action performed by the link. It will help them. If a `title` attribute is not always recommended, you might opt for any solution that would show the text when the element is focused with the mouse or with the keyboard.

You also must remember that not showing text will not help people using voice navigation or eye tracking device.

#### When using the `title` attribute, you must always consider using it conjointly with the `aria-label` attribute, and not replacing one with the other.

---

EDIT: simple example

```css
.icon-link {
background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='50px' width='120px'><text x='0' y='20' font-size='20'></text></svg>");
  content: '';
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block; 
}

#pizza {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  background:white;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a:focus #pizza, a:hover #pizza {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon-link" aria-labelledby="pizza"><div id="pizza">Pizza!</div></a>
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should use all 3 things (`title` attribute, `aria-label` attribute and inner text that's visually hidden) at the same time to provide the most accessibility?

Comment: There are a lot of possible implementations. My preference would go to an `aria-labelledby` hidden element which would become visible on focus (keyboard or mouse). That would mix the three elements together

Comment: You say there are a lot of possible implementations. Do you have any resources that explain possible implementations? That's a problem I have in general - Whenever I have questions about accessible implementations, I find it very hard to find resources that answer those questions.

Comment: I added a very basic implementation in my post