# Screen reader cannot read the visible text inside anchor tag

Tags: html, accessibility, anchor, screen-readers

I have a angular app and it has a drop down menu as below

I use NVDA reader to read the screen.Here when I tab focus it only reads the content inside aria-label.I want it to read the aria label content and other text ('Account',username,email) inside the anchor tag also.

navigation.tpl.html

```html
<ul id="accountMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li class="account" ng-click="openDialog($event)">
    <a class="account-container" role="button" aria-label="Open dropdown" href="#">
      <div href="#" class="dropdown-menu">Account</div>
      <div class="account-name">{{ ::username }}</div>
      <div class="account-email" ng-bind="::email"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `aria-label` generally supersedes an element's inline text content. It may be more effective to put a `.sr-only` span with that text within the anchor. Or if you add a dropdown icon for sighted users, that would be a great place to semantically put that text for screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you overwrote the "account, username, email" text with the `aria-label`.

`aria-label` works as a "say this instead of the contents of this element to a screen reader" attribute, overriding the information within.

If you ever want to add *additional* information you should look at [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute).

However I always encourage people away from using `aria-label` and use **visually hidden text** instead.

It all boils down to support [`aria-label`](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/) doesn't have perfect support, whereas visually hidden text will work all the way back to IE6!

Also visually hidden text works on browsers that do not support CSS (text only browsers), a nice added bonus.

I have created a snippet below to show you how to do this.

### Additional point on semantics

Please note i have also added a second example within the snippet where I changed your anchor (`<a>`) to a `<button>`.

**Semantics matter**, a button indicates an action on the same page, an anchor indicates navigating to another page. Adding `role="button"` to an anchor with no target destination  (#) is way more complicated than using a `<button>` and is far less robust than just using a button in the first place!

It may take a little CSS fiddling but I would suggest you try and follow that pattern of buttons for same page actions, anchors for navigation as it will make your life easier.

### Why not just use `.sr-only`

If you wonder why I would recommend this custom CSS class for hiding text over the standard `.sr-only` class in bootstrap etc. [here is the original explanation I made on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107074/how-to-hide-a-text-and-make-it-accessible-by-screen-reader/62109988#62109988) explaining the issues with `.sr-only` classes as they stand today.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<ul id="accountMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li class="account" ng-click="openDialog($event)">
    <a class="account-container" role="button" href="#">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Open dropdown</span>
      <div href="#" class="dropdown-menu">Account</div>
      <div class="account-name">{{ ::username }}</div>
      <div class="account-email" ng-bind="::email"></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2>A suggestion to improve this further</h2>

<ul id="accountMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li class="account" ng-click="openDialog($event)">
    <button class="account-container">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Open dropdown</span>
      <div href="#" class="dropdown-menu">Account</div>
      <div class="account-name">{{ ::username }}</div>
      <div class="account-email" ng-bind="::email"></div>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```