# Aria expanded placement

Tags: html, dom, accessibility, wai-aria

I am using aria-expanded in an attempt to make my tree list more accessible:

Consider the following:

```
<ul role="tree">
  <li role="tree-item">
     <a href="" aria-label="collapse section" aria-expanded="true"></a>
     <a href="link.html">Link</a>
     <ul role="group">
        <li role="tree-item">List item</li>
        <li role="tree-item">List item</li>
     </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Am I using aria-expanded in the correct place or should it be on the nested UL group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-expanded) should be on the control that opens the sub-tree, so the short answer is yes, it is in the right place assuming that the first anchor is the one that controls the opening.

However there are a few things to consider with the example given.

First of all you should never have a hyperlink that is empty. This should be a `<button>`.

"Buttons Do Things, Links point to URLs" is a great way to think of it, or "Buttons Do Things, Links go places".

Secondly from an ordering point of view your hyperlink "link.html" should be above the current hyperlink that I said to turn into a button. [Otherwise the focus order is not logical so you might not pass WCAG 2.4.3.](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html)

Finally if you are using the first anchor (button) to expand and collapse the section you probably want to add [`aria-controls="idOfTheItem"`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties#aria-controls) to the button as well to ensure the relationship is correct (and add `id="idOfTheItem"` to the `<ul>` to correctly associate them).

Above all test it with a screen reader as there are [certain behaviours expected of a tree view](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/treeview/treeview-2/treeview-2a.html) that may be more difficult as you aren't using a typical pattern for design (for example using arrow keys to navigate).

### A typical pattern

Just so you are aware normally you would make the `<li>` itself open the sub tree. You might get some strange screen reader behaviour adding a button etc. into the `tree-item` as that is not quite expected.

You may be better building a custom widget here that has a list of links with buttons next to them to expand options / additional information.

Without seeing your use case it is very hard to tell.

If you go this route then you could utilise `<details>` and `<summary>` elements.

The following fiddle should give you an idea, notice how it all works without JavaScript (although you will need to polyfill it for IE as [details / summary aren't supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/details))

It would need some [visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) or `aria-labels` etc. to describe each of the `<ul>` if this is a complex tree but like I said just an idea for you to explore depending on your use case as the `role="tree"` doesn't seem to quite fit your pattern.

```css
a{
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="descriptionID">An alternative</h3>
<ul aria-labelledby="descriptionID">
  <li>
     <a href="link.html">Link</a>
     <details>
        <summary>Open</summary>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
     </details>
  </li>
   <li>
     <a href="link.html">Link</a>
     <details>
        <summary>Open</summary>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
     </details>
  </li>
</ul>
```