# accessibility p tag different text for screen reader

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

For a p tag, I need the text that a screen reader reads to be different than the text contained in the p tag.  I need humans to see "Jordan" and the screen reader to read "Michael Jordan." These are in a responsive grid with swiper.js.  Adding title didn't work.  How do I get this to work? (I can use a different HTML tag and attribute to get the same effect.)

```
<p role="title" title="Michael Jordan">Jordan</p>
```

Comment: Why do you want the screen reader to read something different than what is shown on the screen?

Comment: @SuperJade this is in a grid of products that are made with div tags so that it's responsive on small screens and swiper.js library so user can swipe it.  The product titles are at the top of the columns, but they become dis-associated with the specifications as a screen reader reads through the rows of specs and values, and this creates a bad user experience.  I need to do something like add an aria-label to the p tag with the product title and it's value for the screen reader, while the value is just there for the human because the grid is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The golden rule of accessibility is to offer as similar an experience to screen reader users as possible to non screen reader users, as such the following techniques should be used sparingly.

With that being said sometimes context etc. can be important and you need to provide extra information to screen readers.

There are numerous ways to do this:

### 1. `aria-label`

If you give an element an `aria-label` its contents are overridden. However this [doesn't have perfect support](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/), especially on elements such as paragraphs and divs without roles etc.

`<p aria-label="Michael Jordan">Jordan</p>`

#### Update on `aria-label` usage for clarity

I was not clear above as pointed out in the comments.

Hopefully this is more clear, my apologies:

Screen readers will ignore `aria-label` on paragraphs, divs, etc. unless they have a `role` that overrides their semantic meaning.

For example:

`<p aria-label="Michael Jordan" role="heading">Jordan</p>` will work whereas the example I gave above will not and was purely to illustrate `aria-label` usage.

### 2. Visually Hidden Text

A far more robust way of providing extra information to screen reader users is to use [visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894).

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<p><span class="visually-hidden">Michael </span>Jordan</p>
```

### Additional important information

As far as I am aware there is no such thing as `role="title"` - I assume you meant something like `role="heading"` - at which point just use a `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

I removed the `title` attribute from both examples, it is essentially useless nowadays with touch devices not being able to access it, keyboard users never seeing it and it being ignored by a lot of screen readers, generally the advice would be not to use it.

### Final thoughts

Also be aware, for screen reader users who navigate via mouse (i.e. people who use screen readers to assist in comprehension) neither of the above techniques are likely to change what they hear when they mouse over.

As such having the full words would be preferable if you can redesign your interface to accommodate the extra text. Doing this removes the need for any additional markup too so would be the preference.

`<p>Michael Jordan</p>`.

Comment: Screen readers like NVDA don't read the aria-label attribute on "content tags" like p, span, and div - they read the text between the open and close tag.

Comment: I did not phrase it very well at all, I have added an update for clarity, thank you for pointing out that could have been very misleading.

Comment: Also added an extra bit suggesting redesigning the layout so you don't need to do any of the above and the reason why you should do that from an accessibility perspective.