# Correct a11y declaration for a link with just a background image

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to find the best way to improve a11y for links that are built just using background images inside a span (the old school massive icons spritesheets approach). They're part of a large website and changing the whole icon system isn't a realistic scenario right now.

What we basically have are these two different links all around;

First one being the problem:

```
<a href="#" aria-label="Functionality Description">
  <span class="icon-functionality"></span>
</a>
```

The other link style has text in it, so should be fine.

```
<a href="#" aria-label="Functionality Description">
   <span class="icon-text">Functionality</span>
   <span class="icon-functionality"></span>
</a>
```

Trying to find out what should we do in the first case, I found a solution that I'm not sure about; giving the `span` containing the background the `role="img"` and an empty `alt` attribute.

This way, the anchor has an image in it, and by using the empty `alt` attribute, the screen reader would understand it's a decorative picture. In this case, the reader has the `aria-label` associated to the anchor to 'understand' the funcitonality.

```
<a href="#" aria-label="Functionality Description">
  <span class="icon-functionality" role="img" alt></span>
</a>
```

Although I know it's not ideal and in a long term basis we may want to change the whole icon system, would this be enough to provide a decent a11y? What do you think?

All recommendations are welcome. Massive thanks in advance!

Edit to add a screenshot of the Siteimprove error given:

[image: Siteimprove error given]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

There is nothing wrong with the current implementation across the site using `aria-label`s. Your improved example is actually worse for accessibility if the `aria-label` is not read.

### Longer Answer

A background image will not be announced by screen readers and is assumed to be purely decorative.

So the following (your first example) is perfectly acceptable:

```
<a href="#" aria-label="Functionality Description">
  <span class="icon-functionality"></span>
</a>
```

The `aria-label` will provide all of the information a screen reader needs.

In your second example the `aria-label` will override the contents anyway so the `icon-text` is irrelevant as far as a screen reader is concerned.

In your third example you have the same thing with the `aria-label` overriding the contents.

With that being said if you didn't have an `aria-label` having a null `alt` attribute is not correct, it should be an **empty** `alt` attribute to be hidden. (So `alt=""` **not** `alt`, otherwise the screen reader will attempt to find a name for the image (which could result in unexpected behaviour with a background image).

You also now introduced the background image into the accessibility tree (as it would have been ignored before) with `role="img"` so actually made more work for yourself.

### The best Option

A better option is [visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) if you are able to implement that, as it has better compatibility ([`aria-label` isn't 100% supported in all scenarios](https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/aria/) surprisingly) and visually hidden text works in text only browsers.

If you are able to do this then this is the better way to do things due to compatibility, but your `aria-label` method is fine in 99% of scenarios so don't worry too much if this is difficult to implement.

In the following example I have included an inline SVG for demonstration purposes instead of your background image, but the key part is the additional `<span>` with the `visually-hidden` class.

```css
a{
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}

.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="icon-functionality">
  <!----ignore this SVG it is for demonstration purposes only-->
  <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <path fill="#666" d="M549.655 124.083c-6.281-23.65-24.787-42.276-48.284-48.597C458.781 64 288 64 288 64S117.22 64 74.629 75.486c-23.497 6.322-42.003 24.947-48.284 48.597-11.412 42.867-11.412 132.305-11.412 132.305s0 89.438 11.412 132.305c6.281 23.65 24.787 41.5 48.284 47.821C117.22 448 288 448 288 448s170.78 0 213.371-11.486c23.497-6.321 42.003-24.171 48.284-47.821 11.412-42.867 11.412-132.305 11.412-132.305s0-89.438-11.412-132.305zm-317.51 213.508V175.185l142.739 81.205-142.739 81.201z">
        </path>
    </svg></span>
  <!----This is the key part, use this instead of `aria-label` if you can.-->
  <span class="visually-hidden">Functionality Description</span>
</a>
```

### Additional thoughts

Just a quick one but I hope the `href="#"` is for demonstration purposes only.

If you find any anchors on the site using `href="#"` this is an anti-pattern and a bad practice for accessibility.

Instead these should be buttons if they perform an action otherwise they should be valid URLs if they are for navigation.

I only raise this concern as your `aria-label` says "Functionality Description", which makes me think you are using anchors for buttons.

I can link you to several answers on this if you need more info on why this is important for accessibility.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the detailed question @graham-ritchie :)

There are few things that I don't understand though. The reason I was trying to fix it is because we analysed the website with Siteimprove and it marks it as an important error.

It reads: "Links should always have a text alternative. The link can be inserted into the HTML - it does not need to be visible to pass this check".

So it's taking your best option and discarting the other ones. That would cost to implement though!

I thought anything inside the anchor would be overriden by the `aria-label` and I'm a bit lost!

Comment: And yeah, the anchors `href="#"` was mainly for writing it here. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: So with the visually hidden text option you don't use an aria label, the visually hidden text acts as the text, you would remove the existing `aria-label`s. For this reason the part about the `aria-label` overriding the content is no longer applicable.  As for Siteimprove that looks to be an error on their end in the way they process things, I would need to set a test bed up to see, but an `aria-label` is a suitable text alternative. Could you screenshot the exact error (or better yet share the URL of the page with the error if you can) just so I can double check this isn't a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks again Graham!

I've updated the post with the screenshot and the address could be anywhere in the website having an icon... But the original error flagged by Siteimprove seems to be related with the "green document large icon" in this list: https://www.udg.edu/ca/mitjans-de-comunicacio/notes-de-premsa although I've already built a new version with role=presentation for them. This was the backend dev team because they were in a rush.

Comment: Im confused, I ran siteimprove on the page and there were no errors relating to the green icons (which makes sense as you have link text within the hyperlink). The only iamge related error is the SVG in the footer where it complains the link text is the same as the alt text (which is a false positive as the `aria-label` overrides the title of the SVG).

Comment: Ouch, sounds weird. I don't have access to that Siteimprove account since the client sends over the results. I'll let them know. MASSIVE THANKS!

Comment: I've just realised something strange after checking again on Siteimprove; They're using some sort of new version of Siteimprove called NextGen, or it seems so, after seeing the URL on the screenshot. Will clarify with them because it may be the reason of this mess :)