# What's better UX/accessibility: disabled button or link with .active state?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, standards, web-standards

I have a news feed page with two display options: "All Content" and "Personalized Content". I need some buttons or links to let users move between these two options, which involves a page reload and a url parameter (ie - `/?personalized=true`).

[Since it's a page reload, it seems clear that a link should be used for the not-currently active state](https://a11y-101.com/design/button-vs-link). (eg - if I'm on "All", I should use a link to get to "Personalized").

**But what should I use for the currently-active state option: `<a.active>` or `<button disabled>`?**

I'm currently using a `<button disabled>` for the active state and a plain old link for the other one, both styled as links:
[image]

The disabled button (underlined above) has the benefit of being unclickable, which seems to me better UX, as clicking a link and being redirected to the same page you are currently on is annoying. And [omitting the `href` or any of the other tricks to make links unclickable all seem to be poor standards](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/).

But is styling a `button` to look like a `link` just as bad? What does standards/accessibility say about all this?

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @deceze what made you close this one bud? This question is asking about standards, which elements to use etc. I thought that would be Stack Overflow territory more than UX (although the line is blurry as screen reader User Experience would be affected, I regard anything asking about markup guidance and standards as SO territory)?

Answer (score 1):

As the page reloads that is classed as navigation (even if it is the same page with a parameter) so it should be a hyperlink.

Now as for disabling a hyperlink and the associated problems with that, why not just change the element depending on what page you are on?

If you are able just change it to a paragraph with the same styling as a disabled button and add [some visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) to say "currently selected".

`<p>All Content<span class="visually-hidden">(Currently Selected)</span></p>`

If you can't change the element type then I would say just let the page reload if you can and it won't affect things, whatever we do to work around the problem is probably going to be less accessible.

If it will affect things reloading the page and you can't change the item from a hyperlink then maybe you could use `e.preventDefault()` and then add an accessible notification of "you are already on this page".

Your final option would be to redesign the page to not require the refresh and instead load the data via AJAX. There are loads of accessibility considerations there but at least then `<button>` elements make sense and the experience will probably be better for everyone.

### Rough example, current page is "all content" at the moment.

The only thing to add to the above explanation is the use of an `<ul>` to let screen reader users know there are 2 items.

**Please note:**
I have followed your example of underline for active and non-underline for inactive.

In reality you might want to adjust this so that the "current" indicator is to the side instead of underneath, just to avoid confusion as hyperlinks are normally the underlined ones.

A minor point but just something to consider if the design allows.

```css
li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}

li p{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
li a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><p>All Content<span class="visually-hidden">(Currently Selected)</span></p></li>
    <li><a href="/?personalized=true">Personalised Content</a></li>
</ul>
```