# sr-only class causing page scroll

Tags: css, frontend, accessibility, web-frontend

I want to make some content available to screen readers but not visible on the page. Taking it off the page result in screen readers not announcing it, so I'm using a common hacky workaround,  the `sr-only` class, used for instance by Bootstrap. Here's [Kitty Giraudel](https://kittygiraudel.com/snippets/sr-only-class/)'s version:

```
.sr-only {
  border: 0 !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

The problem is with the `position: absolute` rule, which necessitates a parent with `position: relative`. Without it, the invisible content may end up at the bottom of the page and cause the browser to add scrollbars. I don't like having to have to add that `position: relative` rule on top of the `sr-only` class. It can easily be forgotten or accidentally removed. It would be easier if adding the class was the only needed step, which seems possible by simply adding `top: 0` to these rules. But I'm a little nervous tweaking with such ancient wisdom. Is there a reason why it's not commonly done this way? Am I missing a potential issue with `top: 0`?

Comment: A chromium bug was filed for this issue, it describes the issue in more details: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1154640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

No, do not use `top: 0`

### Longer Answer

First the issue you linked in the comments is using a very broken (and old as far as I can tell) screen reader only class, I think it has been updated (and if not then that just reinforces my opinions on using Font Awesome! ).

The [screen reader class you linked](https://kittygiraudel.com/snippets/sr-only-class/) is identical to the [visually hidden text class I created / use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) (which just shows if two of us came up with the same thing it might just be right!) and should not cause the issue described as it uses `clip-path: inset(50%)`.

`clip-path: inset(50%)` effectively makes the element 0px high and 0px wide, so you should never get any overflow issues because of it.

Also the scroll bar issue tends to be caused by the `margin: -1px` part (which you notice we aren't using in our classes), but without something to test against I cannot confirm that is the case here.

As for adding `top: 0` **don't do this** - you are indeed wise to not mess with old wisdom.

The second you start moving the position of the element some screen readers will try and compensate for the positioning (thinking that you are a bad developer and using absolute positioning to change the order of things on the page instead of changing DOM order), resulting in strange reading orders.

I have used the class I linked for 2 years now without ever seeing any unexpected scroll bars so you should be safe.

With all that being said, if you do manage to put together a codepen / fiddle etc. that demonstrates the issue you described with the [class I recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) or the class in your question then please let me know as that is something I would want to address!

### Final thoughts

In the [bug report you linked in the comments](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1154640), **do not** do as the final message suggests:

> 1. Size the element such that it is 0xN, or Nx0 (e.g. "width: 0" or similar).
> 2. Make the element "display: none".
> 3. Surround the element in a 0x0 div which is also "position: absolute".

All 3 of the above options would render the text completely invisible to a screen reader user (remove the element from the accessibility tree) and completely break the point of using a screen reader only class.

Options 4 and 5 are feasible options though:

> 4. Make "viewport-router" a containing block (e.g. "position: relative" or similar).
> 5. Change the "viewport-main" to "overflow-y: hidden" or similar.

Comment: Thanks for so much detail! Sadly your version didn't resolve my case, I still get scrollbars. But glad to know about screen readers and positioning.

Comment: If you want to put a fiddle together I am more than happy to have a look at a workaround for you.