# Possible scroll bug with usage of overflow-hidden on body along with "sr-only" elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, chromium

I encountered an odd problem in the app I'm developing. I'm originally using svelte and tailwind css, however I have reproduced the issue in pure html/css.

In order to achieve a non-scrolling header, I followed some examples I have seen online:
Set the body's size to 100vw x 100vh, and set overflow to be **hidden**, then within that add my **header**, and my **main**, making sure overflow is set to **auto** on the main.

This works great, in my content I have some radio buttons, which also works fine until I add the **sr-only** class from tailwind.

From the moment I add this class, clicking a label that was originally outside the viewport seems to scroll my unscrollable body, causing the layout of the site to be broken,

I have managed to reproduce in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ax7t6ngf/ (code may seem long, but it's just the same element duplicated many times to have some contents to scroll)

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    border-width: 0; /* 2 */
    border-style: solid; /* 2 */
    border-color: #e4e4e7; /* 2 */
}

html {
    line-height: 1.5;
    tab-size: 4;
    font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

nav {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f3f4f6;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.narrow-container {
    max-width: 32rem;
    margin: auto;
}

.font-bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}

.button-group {
    display: inline-flex;
    --tw-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.05);
    box-shadow: black;
}

.radio-button-group {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-width: 1px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.radio-button-group:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.radio-button-group:focus-within{
    color: red;
}

.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            Header
        </nav>
    </header>
        <main>
            <div class="narrow-container">
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">Some Question</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis. Nulla nec purus feugiat, vestibulum
                        mi nec, ultricies metus. Integer sit amet semper turpis.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input class="sr-only" type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-bold">This one doesn't seem to break everything.</p>
                    <p class="italic">
                        The only difference is the lack of "sr-only" class on the input.
                    </p>
                    <div class="button-group" role="group">
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="1">
                            <span>Disappointing</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="2">
                            <span>Under Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="3">
                            <span>As Expected</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="4">
                            <span>Above Expectations</span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-button-group">
                            <input type="radio" value="5">
                            <span>Exceptional!</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>


</body>
</html>
```

To see the problem:

1. Click some of the buttons originally visible without scrolling and notice that nothing crazy happens.
2. Scroll towards the bottom of the page, and click the radios on the very las question (these do not have the sr-only class) and notice that nothing crazy happens.
3. Click on the buttons just above the last question: The layout breaks and most of the page becomes inaccessible.

It is possibly Chrome-related, when I try in Firefox there seems to be no problem.

I've tried different combinations of layouts, and I wonder if maybe I hit a bug in Chrome? Or if I'm the one doing something inherently wrong, I'm not a CSS expert.

I have found this other question: [sr-only class causing page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66572172/sr-only-class-causing-page-scroll) which seems slightly related, and points to a chromium bug https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40734994 which has been closed since.

I have found that taking out the `position: absolute` from the `sr-only` class resolves the problem, but that class is from tailwind, and every other implementation I find also uses `position: absolute` so I'm a little nervous just removing it.

Comment: I'm curious why would you have `.sr-only` on `input`? is it intentional or it's by mistake? I am wondering, do you really want to hide the `input` from everyone except for screen readers only? if you want all users to interact with your inputs, you only need `.sr-only` on label/span.

Comment: I didn't add it myself, the UI library I use did, however, I believe it to be very much on purpose.  The button group I have is meant to behave like radios, with a single one being active at the time, but it doesn't require the radio itself to be visible. The input is still usable by clicking on the label. We could probably not display it at all, but it is my understanding that it would be confusing for screen readers if it wasn't displayed at all, therefore `sr-only` is used to give context to screen readers while not visually displaying the element.

Answer (score 0):

Upon observing the behaviour closer and modifying the `sr-only` class, I have noticed that the way my elements were set-up, the hidden radios ended up on a "layer" lined up with my labels, except this "layer" would not scroll when the underlying div was scrolling, resulting in some of these elements being outside the canvas, and staying there.

Whenever clicking the label corresponding to one of the invisible radios outside the canvas, thus setting the focus on that element, Chrome attempts to bring the element into view. Since scrolling the element meant to be scrolled wouldn't move those, chrome scrolls the body, causing the whole thing to fall apart.

What I have found out is that making my `main` `position:relative` causes the "layer" of radios to now scroll with the rest of the page. When Chrome now scrolls to bring the radio into view, it does so using the intended scrollbar and nothing breaks.

As per https://dev.to/neshaz/css-position-relative-vs-position-absolute-26ok:

> Absolute positioning is done relative to the first relatively (or
> absolutely) positioned parent element. In the case when there is no
> positioned parent element, the element that has position set to
> absolute will be positioned related directly to the HTML element (the
> page itself).

I was indeed being bad at CSS =)