# Accessible way to toggle between an image and a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, wai-aria

So I have a div where the image is shown by default, and the list is hidden. But clicking the button shows the list and hides the image. There will be a grid of these `item` divs.

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__content">
    <img src="..." alt="<Relevant text>" id="image">
    <ul class="hidden" id="list">
      <li>Detail 1</li>
      <li>Detail 2</li>
      <li>Detail 3</li>
      <li>Detail 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="item__heading">
    <div class="item__heading__text">
      <h3>Item name</h3>
      <h4>Item brand</h4>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleContent()" aria-controls="image list">Details</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And currently I just have a CSS class like

```css
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

and a JS function

```js
function toggleContent() {
  const image = document.getElementById("image");
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  image.classList.toggle("hidden");
  list.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this? I'm unsure about the method of hiding things, and also if there is any need for `aria-hidden`?

I should probably note that the `alt` text of the image is important, as the image displays information that users would otherwise not be able to decude.

The two states should look something like[image]

Comment: I wonder if it makes sense to toggle an `sr-only` class for the image instead of `hidden`? It seems more logical to hide the image for sighted users only

Comment: I don't see anything inherently inaccessible about this - noting that elements hidden with `display: none` are also [removed from the accessibility tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370826/which-css-properties-affect-the-accessibility-tree), so there's no need for `aria-hidden`. You'll have to test with actual screenreaders - ideally doing user testing with users who use screenreaders all the time - to determine actual usability, but this is always the case.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="item__content">
      <img src="..." alt="..." id="image">
      <ul class="hidden" id="list">
        <li>Detail 1</li>
        <li>Detail 2</li>
        <li>Detail 3</li>
        <li>Detail 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item__heading">
      <div class="item__heading__text">
        <h3>Item name</h3>
        <h4>Item brand</h4>
      </div>
      <button onclick="toggleContent()" aria-controls="list">Details</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.sr-only {
    border: 0 !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px,0px 0px, 0px 0px);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 0px, 0px 0px,0px 0px, 0px 0px);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
function toggleContent() {
  const image = document.getElementById("image");
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  image.classList.toggle("sr-only");
  list.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Perhaps this makes sense? As mentioned in the comments, this way the list is the only thing really being toggled for screenreader users?