# making a searchform accesible for screenreaders

Tags: html, popup, accessibility

I am using checkbox to show and hide a searchform. When the label is clicked then the checkbox is checked.
So I thought I had sorted it all out, some fancy role and aria atributes here and there make it play nice with accessibility.

CSS is doing the magic:

```
#cb-search-form:checked + .page-search {
    display: block;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="header-icons">
    <label for="cb-search-form" class="btn js-has-popup" id="searchFormLbl" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em"><path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 10-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 001.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 00-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 11-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0111 0z"></path></svg>
        <span class="sr-only">open search form</span>
    </label>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb-search-form">

<div class="page-search js-focus" aria-labelledby="searchFormLbl" aria-hidden="true">
    <label for="cb-search-form" class="btn close js-has-popup-closer" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </label>

    <form action="searchpage" class="form js-page-search" id="form-search" method="POST" novalidate itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
        <meta itemprop="target" content="searchpage?q={q}">
        <!-- the inputs fields and stuff here -->
    </form>
</div>
```

The label seems no valid interaction thingy. The role as button is not realy valid I guess. The tabindex on it is not cooperating at all when I press Enter while focused. The checkbox is not getting checked.
I think this will never get "fixed": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122652

Is this screenreader friendly, I am not even sure if I should "fix" this?

I thought this was nice way to do it like this without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I assume this is meant to be a fall-back for when JS fails / for edge cases where it is switched off and not a JS free solution.

That distinction is important as if this is meant to be a "no JS" solution all of your role information needs removing.

### Best practices with checkboxes as no JS fall-back

What you should do is start with a checkbox and CSS solution (that works with no JS), then through *progressive enhancement*, add the `role="button"` etc. **with JavaScript** rather than having it there in the first place.

You then just treat it as a `<button>` element from that point onwards.

**However,** the `role` needs moving to the `<input type="checkbox"` not the `<label>`, along with all the relevant WAI-ARIA! (see "Focus the checkbox not the label" h2 below)

Also the reason "Enter" does not work is because adding a `role` only changes the *semantic* meaning, it does not add functionality. Checkboxes only work with <kbd>Space</kbd>.

So you would need to add this functionality via JavaScript with `element.addEventListener('keydown'...` and listening for the "Enter" key (key 13) to change the checked state so that it now behaves like a button.

### Focus the checkbox not the label

Finally, when using any checkbox - label "hacks" like this **the item that should receive focus should be the checkbox itself not the label.**

Some screen reader and browser combinations will not announce the checked state for example if you focus the `<label>`.

The other thing to consider is voice navigation, I do not know how something like "dragon naturally speaking" would behave with this. But as I do not know I cannot comment in any meaningful way other than an educated guess that this would not be very robust due to experience with Dragon not behaving well with workarounds.

I mean, [Dragon even has problems with implicit labels](https://a11ysupport.io/tech/html/label_element) so it shows how careful you sometimes have to be due to the scattered support across assistive tech.

#### Changing your CSS / HTML

So you hide the checkbox using a [visually-hidden class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894), but position it in such a way that when it receives focus you can add focus indicators to the label, using something like `input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label{/*your focus indicators*/}`. You need to move the checkbox and the `.page-search` within the `<div class="header-icons"` to use the sibling selector.

I would also encourage you to use the [visually-hidden class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) I linked as the bootstrap `sr-only` class has a few flaws.

Hopefully that makes sense, any questions just ask.

### Quick Demo

I haven't tidied up any of your `role` information etc. in the following demo, all I have done is remove the `tabindex="0"` on the label.

The demo is purely to show how you can focus the checkbox and still put the focus indicator on the label.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}

#searchFormLbl{
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label{
/*your focus indicators*/
outline: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 4px solid #333;
outline-offset: 4px;
}


.page-search{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}

#cb-search-form:checked ~ .page-search {
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-icons">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb-search-form" class="visually-hidden">
    <label for="cb-search-form" class="btn js-has-popup" id="searchFormLbl" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" width="1em" height="1em"><path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 10-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 001.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 00-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 11-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0111 0z"></path></svg>
        <span class="sr-only">open search form</span>
    </label>
<div class="page-search js-focus" aria-labelledby="searchFormLbl">
    I am open
</div>
</div>
```