# Why doesn't JAWS screen reader read my Font Awesome icons?

Tags: accessibility, font-awesome, jaws-screen-reader

I'm testing the JAWS screen reader on a table having the following markup in its cells:

```html
<center><i class="fa fa-check fa-1" title="MyTitle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green" aria-label="read me"></i></center>
```

I've noticed that the screen reader can't "enter" the above cell (due to the `aria-hidden`), so I removed it:

```html
<center><i class="fa fa-check fa-1" title="MyTitle" style="color:green" aria-label="read me"></i></center>
```

Now it can enter the cell but doesn't read any text.

Any way to put some text accessible only to the screen reader and not visible on the UI?

Comment: Note: the `<center>` element has been obsolete for many years. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<center>
  <i class="fa fa-check fa-1" 
     title="MyTitle" 
     style="color:green" 
     aria-label="read me" 
     role="img">
  </i>
</center>
```

Notice how I added `role="img"`, this instructs the screen reader to treat this like an image and so it will read the `aria-label`.

Without it some screen readers will ignore `aria-label` attributes on certain elements as they aren't "semantically correct".

The alternative is to leave the `aria-hidden` on the icon and add some [visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107074/how-to-hide-a-text-and-make-it-accessible-by-screen-reader/62109988#62109988) that is for screen reader users.

Comment: Great solution, I've just tested it and works like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Good luck with the project!

Comment: Just to add here that `aria-label` should only be used on certain types of HTML elements or on elements with certain roles applied. The reason Graham's example works is because `role="img"` has been applied to the same element. You can read more about this here: https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/