# Empty button error in wave accessibility check

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, accessibility

Hello  Im new web developer. i get empty button error from wave.webaim.org - WCAG 2.0 Level AA Accessibility.
Thats the code.

```
<button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev disabled h-hidden" title="none">
```

any help on that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check for WCAG 2.1 as that is the current standard, not WCAG 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

"An Empty Button error means that one of the buttons present on the web page is empty or contains no text describing the function of the button. Or, if it’s an image button, the image contained in the button is missing alternative text."
Source: https://equalizedigital.com/accessibility-checker/empty-button/

It could be that there's no text on the button. If you don't want to put a visible text on the button, you could put a visually hidden text that is read by screen readers, sometimes called the `sr-only` class in css.
More info: [How to hide a text and make it accessible by screen reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107074/how-to-hide-a-text-and-make-it-accessible-by-screen-reader)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have actual text inside the `button`. If you don't want to have a visible text because you style the button in a certain way, using PisteVW solution from above works just fine.

Alternatively, you can use the attribute `aria-label="button text here"` to give the button a label.

Also, you need to remove `role=presentation` as the button performs a clear action, it's not there to simply indicate presentational images, for example: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#presentation

Comment: I tried to add actual text but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you update your post with the new button code, but not only one line, the entire butto0n code, including text and even styling.