# Safari voice over not reading aria-label for a span

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

```
<span tabIndex='0' aria-label={ariaLabelText} className={classesContainer}>
    <span className={classesItem}>{cartItemCount}</span>
</span>
```

I am trying to read the cart item count

Comment: Hey! There is no need for a `tabindex` as screen readers can access the information via the up and down arrows and you should only use `tabindex` on an item that should be interactive (clickable). Is the `aria-label` there to say something different to the content of the inner `<span>` and if so what do you want it to say? `aria-label` is not consistent on non interactive items / items without semantic meaning so it could be that we need to use a different element or approach it in a different way. Are you familiar with a screen reader or new so we can help with relevant controls if needed.

Comment: so we have a cart icon and a ballon to display the number of items in cart.
when the voice over reaches the ballon i want the screen reader to say "x items in cart" it is working as expected in chrome but in safari it not.

Comment: does the answer from @brennnanyoung not sort this problem? A `<button>` or an anchor `<a>` would certainly seem to be the answer here as I would expect the cart icon to lead to a shopping basket? If that doesn't work for your use case then we can make this work using [visually hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894).

Answer (score 2):

As you will discover from [this excellent resource](https://html5accessibility.com/stuff/2020/11/07/not-so-short-note-on-aria-label-usage-big-table-edition/) `aria-label` is not supported on `<span>` because WAI-ARIA specifies `<span>` as a 'generic' role, which in turn means that it **cannot be named**.

You can (of course) override the default role by adding a `role` attribute which supports naming. Choose wisely. If this is going to be keyboard focusable (which your `tabindex` value suggests) then you should choose an operable role, such as `button` or `link`. Better still, use the HTML5 equivalent : `<button>` or `<a>` respectively.

In this particular case, where you simply want to announce the number of items in a cart, I would assume that the 'cart' itself is some kind of **button**, or perhaps a hyperlink, and the number of items in the cart is a kind of **description** or **annotation** for that element.

Your 'cartItemCount' can be included as part of the name, or not as you prefer. In the example below, it is excluded from the name by `aria-hidden`.

Alternatively, an annotation such as this might call for `aria-describedby`, so you might do something like this:

```
<button class="cart" aria-describedby="cartItemCount">
   <span class="visibleLabel">{ShoppingCartText}</span>
   <span aria-hidden="true" id="cartItemCount" class="items">{cartItemCount}</span>
</button>
```

In this example,  'cartItemCount' span is excluded from the button's accessible name (using `aria-hidden`) yet still exposed to assistive technology via `aria-describedby`.

As a design consideration, the 'description' of `aria-describedby` is something which assistive tech users might **prefer to disable**, relying wholly on **naming** (at least sometimes), so your annotation might not be 'announced' if it is not part of the name.

Screen readers and other ATs will offer different ways of accessing or muting this 'description' value when an element is in focus.

Note: [The ARIA annotations spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Annotations), not quite final at time of writing is slated for inclusion in WAI-ARIA 1.3. It offers [the `aria-description` attribute (already supported on some browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=aria-description)) which will allow such state annotations to be added without creating additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

The VoiceOver screen reader on Mac is able to read each element in the page by using Control-Option + left/right/up/down.

Since you are using `aria-label` then you are simply overwriting any text which would be presented inside the span. So, your span would need to use `aria-label="{ariaLabelText} {cartItemCount}"

However, why not simply add everything as a bit of text inside the span and be done with it?

I suspect you want to display a number, be able to tab to that cart number and when you reach there via VoiceOver you want to be able to reflect some extra bit of text to the screen reader users.

For that you need to do something different:

```
<button>
   <span class="visually-hidden">{cartItemText}</span>
   <span class="items">{cartItemCount}</span>
</button>
```

And below is the CSS for the visually-hidden class:

```css
.visually-hidden {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

This way you have interactivity, text displayed in numbers for visual users and also text read out aloud for screen reader users.