# How to correctly set aria-current for the active breadcrumb item

Tags: accessibility, bootstrap-5, wai-aria

I was following the [breadcrumb example of Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/breadcrumb/).

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

You can see the last item has `aria-current`:

```
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
```

However, I also see others put the `aria-current` on anchor:

```
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
        <a href="#" aria-current="page">Data</a>
    </li>
```

I test both with Talkback, only the second implementation successfully announces "current page". But I still want to figure out how to correctly implment the `aria-current` for breadcrumb.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

The first example is still accessible even though `aria-current` is not announced.

Both examples you have given can be used in production and will be perfectly accessible.

### Longer Answer

While according to the spec you should be able to use `aria-current` on a none interactive item, in reality most screen readers / browser combinations will not support it on an item you can't interact with.

Your second example is the "correct" usage, adding it to a hyperlink!

Both of the patterns you provide will be accessible without any issues. The `aria-current` not being announced in the first example is not a problem as the pattern is well known an indicates that "data" is the current page (as it is not a link).

With that being said, you can provide the extra information to screen reader users just for completeness!

We can add "(current page)" in a `<span>`. We can then visually hide that span with CSS so that it is still read by a screen reader but does not change the visual design using a [visually hidden CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894).

I recommend replacing the Bootstrap `.sr-only` class with the one in the fiddle below just because it is more robust.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbs">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data
      <span class="visually-hidden">(current page)</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

This pattern will work in every browser and is the most robust if you want to convey the current page in breadcrumbs to Screen Reader users.

Comment: Thank you so much for both short answer and long  answer, very clear. What make me surprised is the first example is still accessible, cool! I would try your recommendations to provide extra information current page, to make screen reader users more clear. :)

Comment: [Migrating to Bootstrap v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/migration/#helpers) seems to rename `.sr-only` to `.visually-hidden`. :)