# Talkback not announcing dates in the correct format when in a range

Tags: html, date, accessibility, talkback

It seems that when using android talkback, it's not saying the date correctly when there are 2 dates in a range in format of `dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy`

If I had a simple date such as 01/06/2017, it would say it correctly as "First of June, Twenty Seventeen'. However if I had a date range such as 01/06/2017 - 01/06/2018, it would say it as "January Sixth Twenty-Seventeen to January Sixth Twenty-Eighteen", any ideas why?

I have my language set as `en-AU`.

This is the HTML structure:

`<p>01/06/2017 - 01/06/2018</p>`

However, if I put both dates in `<time>` elements, then it reads each date correctly, but separately, e.g. `<p><time>01/06/2017</time> - <time>01/06/2018</time></p>` is read as "First of june, twenty-seventeen", "dash", "first of june, twenty-eighteen", and the whole thing is fragmented so instead of reading it as a line, each element would have to be read separately. But it doesn't work if I wrap the whole thing in `<time>`, i.e. `<p><time>01/06/2017 - 01/06/2018</time></p>` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date ranges are always a tricky thing as there isn't a better way than the one you are using (`<p><time>01/06/2017</time> - <time>01/06/2018</time></p>`)

However there is a way you can force it to say "to", with a quick caveat:
If you use this method then if someone uses auto translate or you internationalise the site at some point it may result in poor translations / a lot of work converting the "to" to other languages.

With that disclaimer out of the way, the trick is to use the actual word "to": `<p><time>01/06/2017</time> to <time>01/06/2018</time></p>`.

But I know what you are thinking, I don't want the word "to" to be visible, I want to use a dash visually.

So now we introduce [`visually hidden text`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) and [`aria-hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) to display one thing but read out another:

```html
<p>
  <time>01/06/2017</time>
  <span aria-hidden="true">-</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">to</span>
  <time>01/06/2018</time>
</p>
```

What we have done is hide the dash from screen readers and then provide some screen reader only text to replace it (another name for "visually hidden" is "screen reader only")

Here is a fiddle demonstrating:

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<p>
  <time>01/06/2017</time>
  <span aria-hidden="true">-</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">to</span>
  <time>01/06/2018</time>
</p>
```

**Note:** Trying to persuade a screen reader to say things a certain way is nearly always a recipe for introducing accessibility issues rather than fixing them. In this instance I think you are fine (hence why I gave an answer), but use this technique sparingly, most of the time screen reader users will be used to strange pronunciations and "fixing" them can actually be more confusing.

Although I have showed you how to "fix" this my personal opinion is that it does not need any intervention, it makes sense with "dash" being read out, but I also think you will not do any harm in this instance if you really want to try this technique out so I will leave the decision up to you.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have done something similar to get it to read the dash as 'to' using `aria-label`, i.e. `<p><time>01/06/2017</time> <span aria-label="to"> - </span> <time>01/06/2018</time></p>`, is there any disadvantages to doing it this way vs the method you provided?

Comment: Also, the other problem is that it would read it in fragments instead of one line. The user would have to physically tap each section for the screen reader to read it out, whereas something like `<p>01/06/2017 - 01/06/2018</p>` gets read out in one go, albeit wrongly. Is there any way to get the screen reader to read it out as a single line instead of fragments? As you said, it's not too big of an issue if it can't be done.

Comment: using `aria-label` on non-interactive items is not consistent (on static content). As for the fragments, I am afraid there is nothing you can do once you start using `<span>`s as the "fix" would be to: hide the whole sentence with the dash in it and replace it with the whole sentence with "to" in it (using `aria-hidden="true"` on the first sentence with the dash and `<span class="visually-hidden"` on the sentence with the "to" in it.), however at that stage you will probably be back at square one! I would say it is fine as it was or with the above technique in my answer.