# Is a HTML label with font-size set to 0 still accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

I would like to hide form field labels but still keep accessibility, would hiding the label by setting it's font-size to 0 still keep the accessibility?

Comment: did you try to write and test?

Comment: Define "accessible". It won't be visible to your average viewer, and if you are trying to cater to screen readers you would be better off doing it properly using e.g. `aria-label` rather than hiding text on the page.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to work everywhere. Use approved ways to do that, such as the definitions of .sr_only / .visually-hidden of known frameworks.

Comment: I assume you want to hide the visual label, but make sure it is still available to ATs (such as screen readers)? Please clarify.

Comment: Quick answer is No. In general, a visible text label is the most accessible choice. Such a label can be implemented with HTML's `<label>` element, with the `for` attribute pointing at the field, or with `aria-labelledby` on the form field pointing at the label. In the latter case, you can use `aria-hidden="true"` on the label to avoid having a duplicate label announcement separately from the one that happens when the form field gets focus. I will second the suggestion to adopt the common CSS idioms for .visually-hidden or .sr_only

Answer (score 3):

No it will not, a font size of 0 will render text as "invisible" to screen readers in majority of cases.

The answer is ["visually hidden text"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894), which will hide the text visually but still make it accessible to assistive technology (the solution linked will work on any browser back to IE7, but there are easier ways to achieve this nowadays).

One last consideration: permanently visible labels help people with cognitive disabilities such as anxiety disorders or learning difficulties.

It is always preferential to adjust the design to include visible labels.

Answer (score -3):

here are different ways to hide your **label** using **css**

```html
<label for="username" style="visibility: hidden">Username 3</label>
```

Comment: Using display:none or visibility:hidden is guaranteed to make the label also unaccessible to screen readers. So this answer is totally wrong.

Comment: unless that was the intention? Question is not entirely clear atm.