# NVDA screen reader not reading div with role status and aria-label

Tags: accessibility, nvda

I have this div `<div role="status" aria-label="chicken"></div>` and NVDA screen reader is unable to read it.  If I change the role to button it works. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug on NVDA part?  It works with other screen readers.

Tested on Chrome.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4yachrtx/

Comment: Aria-label is guaranteed to work everywhere only with interactive elements. The status role don't define an interactive element, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @QuentinC I see.  Then what would be the recommended approach to label a div with role status?

Comment: With respect, @QuentinC, yes, interactive elements have robust support for aria-label but `<div>` elements with a role are also supposed to be supported. See "[2.10 Practical Support: aria-label, aria-labelledby and aria-describedby](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support)". The first bullet point talks about interactive elements, as QuentinC mentioned, but the 3rd last bullet point talks about roles on `<div>` elements. The accessibility tree for the example shows the accname for the `<div>` is "chicken" but neither NVDA nor JAWS announce it. I've never labelled a "live" region.

Comment: @slugolicious it seems in the 3rd last bullet it says. "Other roles besides Landmarks (discussed above) are ignored." So I'm guessing that's why.

Comment: Oh yeah, I read that but I've looked at it so often that my eyes just skimmed over it. Interactive roles and landmark roles seem to honor aria-label but other roles are not guaranteed. Some screen readers might announce them. But as mentioned, I've never used a label on a live region before. I have not seen a use case where it makes sense.

Comment: So perhaps that one possible answer is to wrap the live region inside an element with a landmark role. I was about to recommend `<section>` or `<aside>`, but it seems that aria-label isn't honored everywhere according to the link posted by @Slugolicious (I thought it was robust for all landmarks as well). Test it and if it works, I'll post that as an actual answer.

Comment: I’ve used an `aria-label` on `<section>`and `<aside>` elements before and they are read by screen readers. You might have to change your “verbosity“ settings for JAWS because I don’t think it announces **all** landmark rolls by default.

Answer (score 0):

One fix for non-interactive elements is to fall back to the good old `visually-hidden` class and add a node inside.

```
<div role="status">
  <p class="visually-hidden`>Chicken</p>
  [... other info if applicable]
</div>
```

The item with a `visually-hidden` class will still be accessible to screen readers and other assistive tech, but will not affect the visual aspect of your site.

You can find a visually hidden class that is battle tested (albeit overkill for modern development as it works all the way back to IE6 lol) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894